# Lebesgue measure of $\big\{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\big\}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> What is the Lebesgue measure of $\big\{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\big\}$?

---

Now my intuition would be that this is $0$, since that you can write this set as the union of individual points?

However I am unsure, any clarification would be helpful!

Comment: Note my edit to the question. In proper MathJax usage, the $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ are inside of MathJax, not separate from it. $$ \left\{ \frac 1 n : n\in\mathbb N \right\} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Every* set is a union of sets containing only one point, but not every set is a union of only countably many of them. This one is a union of only countably many such sets.
$$
m\left(\left\{ \frac 1 n : n \in \mathbb N \right\} \right) = m\left( \bigcup_{n\,\in\,\mathbb N} \left\{ \frac 1 n \right\} \right) = \sum_{n\,\in\,\mathbb N} m\left( \left\{ \frac 1 n \right\} \right) = \sum_{n\,\in\,\mathbb N} 0 = 0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ has a limit point $0$ so if we consider the ball $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$  for arbitrary $\epsilon >0$ then except finite number of terms of sequence all are inside that and hence ..

Answer (score 0):

A *countable* union of null sets has Lebesgue measure $0$.

Comment: That's what I thought, so this set is countable? because that may be where my understanding has faltered

Comment: @Geoff: Is ${\mathbb N}$ countable?

Comment: Ah I see, yes thank you!